# How to fix inconsistent browser back-button behavior in fancybox iframe set-up?

Tags: jquery, iframe, browser, navigation, fancybox-2

Having got an on-pageload fancybox iframe working ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26673658/fancybox-iframe-with-content-encoded-in-js-on-launch-page-how-to-open-on-page)), I discover that the set-up produces very different responses to browser back-buttons (a problem that goes way back to the good ol' `frameset` days). If you start here, on Page 1:

- http://www.casedasole.it/fancybox/js/Page1.html

...and go to Page 2, you'll see the starting iframe (which is generated onload from code in Page 2). If you open the link in that iframe, a new document opens in the iframe. Click/touch your back-button, to reload the starting iframe. In testing, browser behaviour is as follows...

**PC Windows 7**

- **Firefox 33** - semi-successful - starting iframe reappears. However, a further click on the back-button produces the starting iframe with no content (iframe blank)
- **Chrome 38** - fails - starting iframe reappears but is blank, content reappears on reload
- **IE 11** - successful - starting iframe re-appears, further click on back-button goes to Page 1 (best result!)

**iPad**

- **Safari** - fails - starting iframe reappears but is blank, content reappears on reload
- **Opera mini** - fails - same as Safari
- **Chrome** - double-fails - goes straight back to back to Page 1

With so many different responses, I doubt there is a solution for all browsers. But maybe someone out there can help.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20618474/1055987 if that helps

Comment: Another interesting article http://www.webdeveasy.com/back-button-behavior-on-a-page-with-an-iframe/

Comment: @JFK Tried webdeveasy.com solution, inserting the script at the end of `var myContent =` in the page that generates the iframe. But no luck (http://www.casedasole.it/fancybox/js/back-button2.html). From your SO answer, looks like I need a combination of two fancybox scripts to get it working - i.e. iframe pop-up onload + your `history.length` hack (see http://www.casedasole.it/fancybox/js/2scripts.html). Is that feasible? Maybe you could post that as answer to the question?

Comment: let me think about it. The issue is that first iframe is created in the DOM so not too sure how it does affect the browser history (if it does)

Comment: @JFK The backbutton bugs I found (http://www.casedasole.it/fancybox/js/back-button.html) seem to apply only when the iframe is created by the starting page. Maybe it's pushing fancybox too far.